# Ignore some classes while scanning PackagesToScan

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, applicationcontext

I've a package (say `packagesToScan`) containing Classes that I wish to persist annotated with `@Entity`.

While defining `ApplicationContext` configuration, I've done as follows.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("packagesToScan")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("server/jdbc.properties")
@ComponentScan("packagesToScan")
```

public class JpaContext {

...
// Other configurations
  ....

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
    emf.setPackagesToScan("packagesToScan");
    emf.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
    return emf;

 }
```

While developing, I've some classes within `packagesToScan` which doesn't satisfy requirements for persistence (like no primary keys etc) and due to this I'm not allowed to run test because of `ApplicationContext` setup failure.

Now,
**Is there any way that I can scan just some selected classes or ignore some classes within `packagesToScan`?**

Comment: You can remove/comment the @Entity annotation untill your entity is complete. Than it won't be picked up by persistence provider.

Comment: Isn't it possible to scan just some particular entities that I want to test with?

Comment: You can also remove packagesToScan option, create persistence.xml and list entities here. I still don't understand your motivation to exclude some entities - you can easily remove @Entity annotations if you are in the middle of the development and your entity isn't complete, or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you ever find a solution to ignore some entities within `packagestoscan` ?

Comment: @nilgun No, I haven't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have been trying to solve the same problem and finally got a solution as below:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.bean"/>
    <property name="entityTypeFilters" ref="packagesToScanIncludeRegexPattern">
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        // ...
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="packagesToScanIncludeRegexPattern" class="org.springframework.core.type.filter.RegexPatternTypeFilter" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="^(?!com.mycompany.bean.Test).*"/>
</bean>
```

I realized that there is a [`setEntityTypeFilters` function](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setEntityTypeFilters-org.springframework.core.type.filter.TypeFilter...-) on the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` class which can be used to filter which classes to be included. In this example I used [RegexPatternTypeFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/type/filter/RegexPatternTypeFilter.html) but there are [other types of filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/type/filter/TypeFilter.html) as well.

Also note that the filters work with include semantics. In order to convert to exclude semantics I had to use negative lookahead in the regex.

This example shows the xml configuration but it should be trivial to convert to java based configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon a simmilar problem. I needed to add some but not all entities from a package. Here is how I did it:

```
// add all entities from some package
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.companyname.model");
// add only required enitites from a libray
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(new PersistenceUnitPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnit) {
            persistenceUnit.addManagedClassName("com.companyname.common.model.SomeEntityName");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to use `setPackagesToScan` and then remove unwanted packages. It turns out that `persistenceUnit.getManagedClassNames()` in `PersistenceUnitPostProcessor` returns a regular `ArrayList` which can be manipulated.

```
em.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(new PersistenceUnitPostProcessor() {
    @Override
    public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnit) {
        List<String> managedClassNames = persistenceUnit.getManagedClassNames();
        managedClassNames.removeIf(fullClassName -> fullClassName.startsWith("com.example.twodatasources.product"));
    }
});
```

In my case the shown persistanceUnit is responsible for all entities but the ones in `com.example.twodatasources.product` package. The other one in responsible only for `com.example.twodatasources.product`.

The code above is for the hibernate part. It's worth to mention that the spring part should also be filtered. This can be achieved by adding a ComponentScan.Filter to `@EnableJpaRepositories` as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.yml" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.example.twodatasources",
    excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.example\\.twodatasources\\.product\\..*")},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used entityTypeFilters to ignore some classes while scanning PackagesToScan

but as I found out setting entityTypeFilters via

```
<property name="entityTypeFilters" ref="packagesToScanIncludeRegexPattern">
```

clears existing default filters which are(according documentation):

*Specify custom type filters for Spring-based scanning for entity classes.
Default is to search all specified packages for classes annotated with @javax.persistence.Entity, @javax.persistence.Embeddable or @javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass.*

As I checked in debug this is resulted in having all class packages being scanned by spring which match packagesToScan condition except packagesToScanIncludeRegexPattern regex. This has impact on startup time.

As workaround I implemented custom filter with filters as by default puls regexp filter:

```
public class RegexPatternEntitiesTypeFilter extends AbstractClassTestingTypeFilter {

private final Set<String> entityPackageRegistry;
private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!my.company.package.exclude).*");

public RegexPatternEntitiesTypeFilter() {
    entityPackageRegistry = ImmutableSet.of(Entity.class.getName(), Embeddable.class.getName(),
        MappedSuperclass.class.getName());
}

@Override
protected boolean match(ClassMetadata metadata) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (metadata instanceof AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor) {
        Set<String> annotationTypes = ((AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor) metadata).getAnnotationTypes();
        result = !Sets.intersection(entityPackageRegistry, annotationTypes).isEmpty();
    }
    boolean matches = this.pattern.matcher(metadata.getClassName()).matches();
    return result && matches;
}
```

}