# How just scan a concrete JPA entity but not all entities bellow the same package with spring-boot?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I have multiple JPA entities bellow the same package, such as `my.package.po.EntityA` and `my.package.po.EntityB`. Use bellow code will auto scan both EntityA and EntityB, but I just want to scan EntityA. How can I do this?

```
package my.package.dao;
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EntityADaoJpaImpl.class})
@DataJpaTest
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {EntityA.class})
public class EntityADaoJpaImplTest {
    @Inject
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Inject
    private EntityADaoJpaImpl dao;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Seems that your problem was fixed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293437/ignore-some-classes-while-scanning-packagestoscan

Comment: That need to write more complicated code. Does have someway like @EntityScan(classes = EntityA.class) ?

Answer (score 3):

After some research, specially follow '[ignore-some-classes-while-scanning-packagestoscan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293437/ignore-some-classes-while-scanning-packagestoscan#answer-40909775)' idea:

```
// add only required enitites from a libray
localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(new PersistenceUnitPostProcessor() {
  @Override
  public void postProcessPersistenceUnitInfo(MutablePersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnit) {
    persistenceUnit.addManagedClassName("my.package.po.EntityA");
  }
});
```

I make some custom code encapsulation to simplify my unit-test:

```
package my.package.dao;
import tech.simter.test.jpa.EntityScan;
import tech.simter.test.jpa.JpaTestConfiguration;
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {EntityADaoJpaImpl.class, JpaTestConfiguration.class})
@DataJpaTest
@EntityScan({EntityA.class})
public class EntityADaoJpaImplTest {
  @Inject
  private TestEntityManager entityManager;
  @Inject
  private EntityADaoJpaImpl dao;
  //...
}
```

It totally resolve my problem. And the code encapsulation idea comes from the implementation of spring-boot-autoconfigure `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan` class.

My source code hosts [here](https://github.com/simter/simter-test/commit/01bca2f8cf37c410eb555272eb93b8dc6e630a86). It is on github.

Comment: Really useful solution. The only drawback is the selected class must not have any associations to other entity classes. Otherwise the entity manager tries to load all associations anyway, which fails.